# iCloud file storage/exchange across devices

Tags: ios, icloud, document

I am trying to store data to iCloud documents, and read it on another device logged in with the same account.

I can detect iCloud, send data to iCloud and read it back on the same device.  I can detect the file is there from the second device, but I get an error 'NSCocoaDomainError - code 260' when I try to read or copy the file.

File Store code:

```
//CREATE FILE
NSError *error;

NSLog(@"string to write:%@",printString);
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if (ubiq == nil) {
    return;
}
NSURL *cloudURL =[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CogwindInventory.txt"];
[printString writeToURL:cloudURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Code to run the query:

```
self.backups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[self.query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K like 'CogwindInventory.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
[self.query setPredicate:pred];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGatheringRestore:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                           object:self.query];
[self.CloudActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.query startQuery];

- (void)queryDidFinishGatheringRestore:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSMetadataQuery *query = [notification object];
    [query disableUpdates];
    [query stopQuery];

    [self loadDataRestore:query];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

    self.query = nil;
}


- (void)loadDataRestore:(NSMetadataQuery *)query {
    [self.backups removeAllObjects];

    for (NSMetadataItem *item in [query results]) {
        NSURL *url = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        //[self.backups addObject:url.lastPathComponent];
        [self.backups addObject: url.filePathURL];
    }
    if (self.backups.count > 0) {
        [self retrievefile];
    }
    [self OperationComplete];
}
```

Code to do the read:

```
- (void) retrievefile
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *ubiq = [self.manager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

    if (ubiq == nil) {
        return;
    }
    NSURL *cloudURL =[self.backups objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *localtoken = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:cloudURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    if ((localtoken == nil) || (error !=nil)) {
        [self.CloudStatusText setText: @"Restore operation failed."];
        return;
    } else {
        [self.tokeninventory setPlayerInventoryNames:localtoken];
        [self.CloudStatusText setText: @"Restore operation successful. New inventory available"];
    }

}
```

The devices are OS 8.1.1 and OS 8.3.  iCloud- Documents is enabled in Xcode, but not iCloudKit.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: ran another test on the second iPad. Checked the FileManager for fileExistsAtPath and it shows it doesn't exist, even though the query says it's there.  The URL's and paths seem consistent and correct.  Is this a permission problem?

Comment: Ok. New data. I up'd the build number, performed a Clean, Performed an Archive, and Validated the build.  This forced the Provisioning Profile to update again, with the new build number.  Xcode was pausing periodically for a couple minutes per, and I noted the Xcode version is 7.0.1.  I don't remember updating past 7.0, but I may have.  Long story short it is working now, although I have to give the device a couple minutes to update the cloud, after the Store option has been done.